# How to remove empty folder name include whitespace in a directory using BATCH script?

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below to remove empty folder in a directory using BATCH script.

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /b /a:d "C:\test\*"') do >nul 2>nul dir /a-d "%%i\*" || ( rd "%%i" )
```

But it will not remove empty folder when folder name include whitespace. (for example "34567 1")

I try using `rd "34567 1"` and the folder can delete successfully.

I am using the below to try to show folder name.

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /b /a:d "C:\test\*"') do >nul 2>nul dir /a-d "%%i\*" || (echo "%%i" && rd "%%i" )
```

If the folder name include whitespace `%%i` is "系統找不到指定的檔案。" ("The system can not find the specified file" translation from google)

How can remove empty folder name include whitespace in a directory using BATCH script?

Comment: For /f will by default use `"tokens=1 delims= "` So %%i will only contain the path upto the first space. Either insert `for /f "delims=" ...` or `For /f "tokens=*" ...` to resolve this.

Comment: wow it works!!
can you post this message on answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For /f` will by default use `"tokens=1 delims= "`

So `%%i` will only contain the path up to the first space.

Either insert `for /f "delims=" ...` or `For /f "tokens=*" ...` to resolve this

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (
    'dir /b /a:d "C:\test\*"'
) do >nul 2>nul dir /a-d "%%i\*" || ( rd "%%i" )
```

See `for /?` for details or read http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html